# The new Calculus?

Tags: calculus

I read through some of John Gabriel's the new calculus last night, he does seem quite arrogant but some of the things he says seems to make sense. For example is  his way of taking derivatives based of parallel secant lines right? To me it just seems like rolls theorem. Is this guy correct with his new Calculus or can it be ignored?

Comment: Just to save others the trouble of googling: http://thenewcalculus.weebly.com/

Comment: And based on just the introduction, it sure looks like a crank. “The New Calculus is the first and only rigorous formulation of calculus in human history.” “Neither Newton nor Leibniz nor anyone who came after them understood calculus as well as I do. In fact, no one in the history of humans has understood calculus as well as I.”

Comment: Yeah its comments like that threw me off

Comment: Is this some sort of joke?  I can't imagine most people would read past the empty bragging, certainly I won't.  If there is a new result, great!  The author should state that and let people verify/reject it.  Significant new results are always worthy of attention.

Comment: It's just he seems to get all the usual rules from his alternative approach which is why i'm interested

Comment: John Gabriel is a textbook case of delusional disorder which are often referred to as cranks but it's a serious mental illness and he doesn't have much control over it. He just doesn't have the ability to see the world clearly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delusional_disorder

Comment: LOL he calls limits an "unsound concept."

Comment: Even more cranky: “The New Calculus is not worth just one Abel prize, it is worth ten Abel prizes.”

Comment: Crackpots are everywhere.

Comment: Untoppable: “I am also the first human since Euclid to produce the perfect derivation of number.”

Comment: Reading this, @CyclotomicField is exactly right.  This is on the same (sad) level as Zim Mathematics.

Comment: Not sure why Mr. Gabriel wants all those Abel prizes, as they're named after a man who helped lead us into all this academic ignorance and stupidity.

Answer (score 6):

There are interesting alternatives to the standard formulation of calculus; here I am thinking of Abraham Robinson's nonstandard analysis (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonstandardAnalysis.html) and Errett Bishop's constructive approach (see e.g. https://books.google.dk/books/about/Foundations_of_constructive_analysis.html?id=Z7I-AAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y). Robinson and Bishop were accomplished mathematicians.

However, anyone who makes the claim that

> The New Calculus is not worth just one Abel prize, it is worth ten
>   Abel prizes. Of course you will never know unless you study my work.

of his/her own work (cited from http://thenewcalculus.weebly.com) and writes that

> Neither Cauchy sequences nor Dedekind cuts are valid constructions of
>   real numbers.

is speaking the language of crackpots.

Comment: I'm interested in how he's getting correect results with this other theory or is it because he is starting from things already established in calculus and picking and choosing as he likes?

Comment: With sufficient geometric intuition you can get correct calculus results even if you can't justify them rigorously. The inventors of calculus (Newton, Leibniz and others) did that well before rigor came to mean what it does today.

Comment: Is his lack of rigor why he says thinks are just obvious and that there are no axioms because they are so obvious then?

Comment: Here is a real life quote from this guy: "Dedekind was an idiot next to me."

Comment: If I ever had to stand next to that guy, I, too, would feel like an idiot.

Comment: He gets results that are indefinite (it's a bit hard to see because he ties himself and the reader into tangles of auxiliary quantities) which he resolves by picking the one that normal calculus already told you it was. He is unaware of the ambiguity (which does not speak well for his intellect) or he is and not telling the reader (which does not speak well for his ethics). So, Jake: it's option number 2